# Installing Azure SDK without Emulators

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-storage

Is it possible to install the Azure SDK (specifically VS 2015) without installing the associated emulators.

Simply I just never use them, and it would be good to not install them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually download the SDK files by visiting [`Azure SDK for .NET`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=92a579d2-26ae-4c15-924a-b95edd9834d6) link here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/downloads/archive-net-downloads/. You will be redirected to Microsoft Download page and there you will be able to select the components that you want to download.

Comment: Thanks! I just found that (they're installing) had just come back to write an answer.